# list folders and subfolders at the last level php

Tags: php

I need to monitor whether within a directory I have empty folders to generate alerts for users.

This script I thought of doing in php due to infra will run once a day.

I found several examples, but none that help me to list empty folders to the last level.

Example:

```
Root / Folder1 / year / month / file.pdf
Root / Pasta2 / year / month
```

In folder 2 I know it's empty and I need to get all these cases.

I tried it

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../Vistorias/');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    echo $filename . ' - ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';
}
```

Result:

```
../Vistorias/. - 256 bytes 
../Vistorias/.. - 416 bytes 
../Vistorias/.DS_Store - 14340 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-3/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-3/.. - 256 bytes 
../Vistorias/Paste-2/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/Paste-2/.. - 256 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/. - 160 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/.. - 256 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/.DS_Store - 6148 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/Sub-pasta-1-a/. - 96 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/Sub-pasta-1-a/.. - 160 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/Sub-pasta-1-a/export.pdf - 3959 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/vazia/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/vazia/.. - 160 bytes
```

I would like to have a return like this:

```
../Vistorias/Pasta-3/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/Paste-2/.. - 256 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/Sub-pasta-1-a/export.pdf - 3959 bytes 
../Vistorias/Pasta-1/vazia/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/teste/. - 96 bytes 
../Vistorias/teste/trigo.png - 1727287 bytes
```

So I would know that the folders below are empty:

```
../Vistorias/Pasta-3/. - 64 bytes 
../Vistorias/Paste-2/.. - 256 bytes
```

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more details to your question

Comment: Right! I added more information to the question. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - extract the path from the file name, use that as key for an array, and sum up the number of directory entries you encounter. For an empty directory, that count will be 2 - because of the entries `.` and `..`. So anything else that has a different count can be removed from the final array using array_filter.

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../Vistorias/');
$folders = [];
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    $path = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
    // entry for path either already exists, then add one - or initialize with 1
    $folders[$path] = isset($folders[$path]) ? $folders[$path] + 1 : 1;
}
// filter all entries with a count != 2, and apply array_keys
// to get the folder names, which are currently the keys, to become the values
// again in the final result
$folders = array_keys(array_filter($folders, function($count) { return $count == 2; }));
```

Comment: Thank's for your time! It was exactly what I needed.